# Lightning Data Service not updating field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-data-service

I am having 2 issues. One is, when I am updating a field, there are some field validations that are not getting flagged in my code. The second is when I have met the criteria, the field does not update. I am using LDS and not apex code since I am trying to understand how LDS works (I already have a working copy using apex).

cmp:

```
<aura:attribute name="account" type="Object" 
  description="The record object to be displayed"/>
<aura:attribute name="accountRecord" type="Object" 
  description="A simplified view record object to be displayed"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordSaveError" type="String" 
  description="An error message bound to force:recordData"/>

  <force:recordData aura:id="accRec" 
    layoutType="FULL" 
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"  
    targetError="{!v.recordSaveError}"
    targetRecord="{!v.account}"
    targetFields="{!v.accountRecord}"
    mode="EDIT"
    recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}"/>


 <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordSaveError))}">
           <br />
        <div class="error slds-box">
             {!v.recordSaveError}
        </div> 
    </aura:if>
```

Js controller:

```
  handleClick: function(component, event, helper){

     helper.saveAccount(component, event, helper);

},

 recordUpdated : function(component, event, helper) {
     helper.recordUpdated(component, event, helper);
}
```

Helper:

```
({
saveAccount : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find("accRec").set("v.accountRecord.field1", true);  //Field to update
    component.find("accRec").saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(saveResult) {
        if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
            alert("Save completed successfully.");
        } else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            component.set("v.recordSaveError","User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
        } else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") { 
            var errMsg = "";
            // saveResult.error is an array of errors, 
            // so collect all errors into one message
            for (var i = 0; i < saveResult.error.length; i++) {
                errMsg += saveResult.error[i].message + "\n";
            }
            component.set("v.recordSaveError", errMsg);

        } else {
            component.set("v.recordSaveError",'Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state + ', error: ' + 
              JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
        }
    }));

    $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();  
},

recordUpdated : function(component, event, helper){
    var changeType = event.getParams().changeType;
    if (changeType === "CHANGED") {
        component.find("accRec").reloadRecord();
    }
}


})
```

Comment: to set the field you should do: `component.set("v.accountRecord.field1", true);'